# Need Help implementing swipe tab view with navigation drawer

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have implemented swipe tab view in one of the fragments of navigation drawer activity.

Problem is - when I open that fragment for the first time, everything works fine. But when I switch to another fragment and then return back, some of the tabs in my swipe tab view don't display anything while some tabs display properly. 
And I can't find any pattern in tabs which are missing data on returning back.

Here's is how I have implemented it -

HourlyFragment.java

```
public class HourlyFragment extends Fragment {

    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private View view;
    private FragmentActivity myContext;

    public HourlyFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hourly, container, false);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(myContext.getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        myContext=(FragmentActivity) context;
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return new Graph();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return ("Test1").toUpperCase(l);
                case 1:
                    return ("Test2").toUpperCase(l);
                case 2:
                    return ("Test3").toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Graph.java

```
public class Graph extends Fragment {

    public Graph() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_graph, container, false);
    }

}
```

graph.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

HourlyFragment.xml

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
                android:background="@android:color/white">

                <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
                    android:id="@+id/pager_tab_strip"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp" />

            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Note - For demo purpose I am displaying the same fragment (Graph) in each tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using ViewPager inside Fragment. Use **getChildFragmentManager()** instead of **new SectionsPagerAdapter(myContext.getSupportFragmentManager());**

Your code must be looks like this:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hourly, container, false);
mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
return view;
```

Try it!

Comment: Thanks. Its working flawlessly now. But can you please explain how my code was working the first time and not after that ?

Comment: Your code can work with simple FragmentManager. But behavior of pages may be different than you think. You need to learn Fragment's lifecycle deeply as possible.